# Custom wheel file on EMR and on EMR Notebook

Tags: python, amazon-emr

I'm trying to install a custom wheel, which is not on PyPI, on my EMR cluster.

I used a bootstrap action to download the wheel file from S3 and used pip install to install the wheel.
The log shows this is completed successfully.

When running from an EMR notebook the module from the wheel doesn't exist. I have tried using the three available kernels in the notebook: PySpark, Spark and Python 3 but the module isn't available.

Also, I tried SSH-ing into the node, and there execute

```
pip list
```

where I see my installed wheel

Also when I run python and import my module inside the SSH session this is successful.

My questions are:

1. which Python will be used if I run a Spark EMR job using spark submit, and is it different or the same as one of the kernels available in the EMR notebook?
2. Should I install a wheel file on EMR cluster differently?

Comment: 1. you can verify the python version of the cluster with opening a pyspark shell in the ssh session

2. You can build an environment with your dependencies using one of the following methods from this article: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html